# Fast interpolation over 3D array for 3D origin x

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

This problem is similar to a former problem answered [Fast interpolation over 3D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488631/fast-interpolation-over-3d-array), but cannot solve my problem.

I have a 4D array with dimensions of (time,altitude,latitude, longitude), marked as `y.shape=(nt, nalt, nlat, nlon)`. The x is altitude and change with (time, latitude, longtitude), which means `x.shape = (nt, nalt, nlat, nlon)`. I want to interpolate in altitude for every (nt, nlat, nlon). The interpolated x_new should be 1d, not change with (time, latitude, longtitude).

I use `numpy.interp`, same as `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and think about the answers in former post. I cannot reduced the loops with those answers.

I can only do like this:

```
# y is a 4D ndarray
# x is a 4D ndarray
# new_y is a 4D array
for i in range(nlon):
    for j in range(nlat):
        for k in range(nt):
            y_new[k,:,j,i] = np.interp(new_x, x[k,:,j,i], y[k,:,j,i])
```

These loops make this interpolation too slow to calculation. Would someone have good ideas? Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If new_x is in ascending order, I think you can write a Cython function to increase the calculation speed.

Comment: @HYRY The new_x is in ascending order. But the original x may be not in ascending order. Is this available? I don't familiar with Cython, maybe need some time to learn it or can learn tiago's code in former post.

Comment: but, `numpy.interp` need `x` in ascending order, you need to sort both x, y by x first.

Comment: yes, i will check the original x and y. Thanks a lot~

Comment: I tried to speedup this, but it seems that `np.interp()` is very fast already. can you tell us what is the shape of `new_x` and `x`. And make the `nalt` axis as the last axis will increase the calculation a little.

Comment: The x.shape=(nt, nalt, nlat, nlon), x means the heights of vertical layers for each (time, latitude, longitude). New_x is although heights of vertical layers, but keep the same over the world, so new_x.shape=(nalt).

Comment: I want to know the real number.

Comment: the real number for `new_x = [280., 282.5, 285., 287.5, 290., 292.5, 295., 297., 297.5, 298., 298.5, 299., 299.5, 300., 301., 302., 303., 304., 305., 306., 307., 308., 309., 310., 312., 315., 319., 322., 326., 330., 333., 334., 337., 339., 341., 343., 345., 347., 349., 353., 357., 363., 371., 375., 380., 385., 390., 393., 417., 484., 525., 582., 597., 669., 695., 797., 853., 914., 962., 1089., 1161., 1238., 1312., 1482., 1887., 2051., 2346., 2609., 3155.]`. This is the potential temperature(T) of 69 layers. The original x is potential T with a size of (132*66*96*144). It is too long to post.

Comment: The original x are potential temperatures of 66 layers for 132 time slices. The horizontal grid is 96*144. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution by using numba, it's about 3x faster.

create the test data first, `x` need to in ascending order:

```
import numpy as np
rows = 200000
cols = 66
new_cols = 69
x = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
x.sort(axis=-1)
y = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
nx = np.random.rand(new_cols)
nx.sort()
```

do 200000 times interp in numpy:

```
%%time
ny = np.empty((x.shape[0], len(nx)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    ny[i] = np.interp(nx, x[i], y[i])
```

I use merge method instead of binary search method, because `nx` is in order, and the length of `nx` is about the same as `x`.

- `interp()` use binary search, the time complexity is `O(len(nx)*log2(len(x))`
- merge method: the time complexity is `O(len(nx) + len(x))`

Here is the numba code:

```
import numba

@numba.jit("f8[::1](f8[::1], f8[::1], f8[::1], f8[::1])")
def interp2(x, xp, fp, f):
    n = len(x)
    n2 = len(xp)
    j = 0
    i = 0
    while x[i] <= xp[0]:
        f[i] = fp[0]
        i += 1

    slope = (fp[j+1] - fp[j])/(xp[j+1] - xp[j])        
    while i < n:
        if x[i] >= xp[j] and x[i] < xp[j+1]:
            f[i] = slope*(x[i] - xp[j]) + fp[j]
            i += 1
            continue
        j += 1
        if j + 1 == n2:
            break
        slope = (fp[j+1] - fp[j])/(xp[j+1] - xp[j])   

    while i < n:
        f[i] = fp[n2-1]
        i += 1

@numba.jit("f8[:, ::1](f8[::1], f8[:, ::1], f8[:, ::1])")
def multi_interp(x, xp, fp):
    nrows = xp.shape[0]
    f = np.empty((nrows, x.shape[0]))
    for i in range(nrows):
        interp2(x, xp[i, :], fp[i, :], f[i, :])
    return f
```

Then call the numba function:

```
%%time
ny2 = multi_interp(nx, x, y)
```

To check the result:

```
np.allclose(ny, ny2)
```

On my pc, the time is:

```
python version: 3.41 s
numba version: 1.04 s
```

This method need an array that the last axis is the axis to be `interp()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's great! I will check it tomorrow.